# Applescript - Contacts: Why can I get addresses and emails from a contact but not phones

Tags: applescript, contacts.app

### Errors when getting phones

In Script Editor, if I run:

```
tell application "Contacts" to get the vcard of person 301
```

the result is:

```
"BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.13.6//EN
N:Bar;Foo;;; FN:Foo Bar
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=pref:foobar@gmail.com
TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE;type=pref:555 555 1212
CATEGORIES:Address Book
UID:1e6e6e410a662666
X-ABUID:18B18941-E2B7-48CE-BB34-4A26CC0E23BB:ABPerson
END:VCARD
"
```

Note that this person has an email address and a phone number. If I run:

```
tell application "Contacts" to get the value of emails of person 301
```

the result is:

> {"foobar@gmail.com"}

However if I run:

```
tell application "Contacts" to get the value of phones of person 301
```

I get

> **error** "Contacts got an error: Can’t get value of every phone of person 301." number -1728 from value of **every** *phone* **of** *person* 301

and if I run

```
tell application "Contacts" to get the phones of person 301
```

> **error** "Contacts got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

### What happens if the person doesn't have a phone number?

*Edit:* Based on one of the proposed answers to this post, I tried

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set thePhoneNumber to value of phones of people
end tell
```

which gave me something like

> {*missing value*, {}, *missing value*, *missing value*, ...}

with a lot more "missing values" and "{}s" because I have about 2000 entries in the database.

Investigating this, I found that the "missing value" appears for people who have phone numbers, and the "{}" appears for people who *do not* have phone numbers. If I run the same command with "emails", I get a list of email addresses for each person who has emails, and an empty list "{}" for people who don't.

---

This is on Mac OS 10.13.6, Contacts 11.0 (1808.8).

Have I discovered a bug or is there something wrong with my script?

Comment: It's a bug in _Contacts_, which you could report to Apple (the more people that file bug reports, the more likely they are to prioritise fixing the issue).  You might have to parse the vCard data yourself to retrieve the phone number.

Comment: @CJK thanks, I used https://bugreport.apple.com/ to submit a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you...

```
tell application "Contacts"
    launch
    delay 1
    tell its person 301
        try
            set thePhoneNumber to value of phones
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

This also works for me...

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set thePhoneNumber to value of phones of its person 301
end tell
```

You can also try running this following code

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set thePhoneNumber to value of phones of people
end tell
```

Then you will go to item 301 of that result and if there is no phone number... That may be why you are getting the error.

Comment: The result is still error -10000, "Contacts got an error: AppleEvent handler failed."

Comment: Updated the code to try that new version

Comment: Unfortunately, @wch1zpink, the code still doesn't work on my machine. See the edits I made to my question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is.I'm using the exact same operating system version and version of contacts. Did you try the second code sample in my answer?